# Why is value of variable not incremented in constructor

Tags: java

I created a program that creates a card, which will contain a number, name and status. I want the user to be able to set the name for the user of the card but I want the number to be sequential, so a new one for every card created starting at 1. I set the value of the first card at 1 and then call the method to increment its value for the next card inside the constructor but when I run it in a test class it always gives out number 2. Help's appreciated!

Leaving the variables, constructor, increment method, toString method and test class below.

```
public class CartaoCliente {

    long numCartao = 1;
    String nome;
    Boolean estado;

    public void incCartao(){
    numCartao++;
    }

    public CartaoCliente(String nomeCartao){
        incCartao();
        this.nome = nomeCartao;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
    return "Número: " + numCartao + ", Nome: " + nome; //overriden to print below
    }
}

public class TesteCartao {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CartaoCliente c = new CartaoCliente("José");
        CartaoCliente d= new CartaoCliente("Esdrubal");
        System.out.println(c.toString()); 
        System.out.println(d.toString());

    }
    
}
```

Comment: you need to make numCartao static at least, or use atomiclong in case of multithreading

Comment: I tried making it static before but it still did the same.

Comment: @nuno You need a static field which holds the next id value for a new instance and another non-static field for the current number for that new instance you create.

Comment: yup! that fixed it. cheers

Answer (score 0):

solution from @Progman

```
public class CartaoCliente {

    static long numCartao = 1;
    String nome;
    Boolean estado;
    long novoNum;

    public void incCartao(){
    novoNum = numCartao++;
    }
   
    @Override
    public String toString(){
    return "Número: " + novoNum + ", Nome: " + nome; //overriden to print below
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't really a good idea. You should use `AtomicLong` instead

Comment: Also, this is generally what databases with `AUTOINCREMENT` fields are for.

Comment: will look into it and do it like that as well, thanks.